# How to send logs to Graylog (Docker)?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, graylog2, graylog

I'm new to both Docker and Graylog. Can anyone show me an example of how to send log data to the Graylog server?

Comment: What kind of logs (from which kind of applications or devices) do you want to collect?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, it is pretty easy! Graylog's preferred Log Format - GELF - is supported by Docker natively. So if you are using Docker logs already (Docker's internal logging functionality) you can just use Docker's built-in support, that will forward all logs from your container to the specified GELF endpoint. You will have to create a GELF UDP input on the Graylog server.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

For running a container from command line that sends all logs to Graylog via GELF just use the options `log-driver` and `gelf-address`:

```
docker run -dit \
--log-driver=gelf \
--log-opt gelf-address=udp://192.168.0.42:12201 \
alpine sh
```

Comment: You should consider these issues when using the gelf driver in production: https://blog.docker.com/2017/02/adventures-in-gelf/

Comment: I couldn't send exceptions that when starting container it gets, to Graylog. Do I have to use udp ? I am using tcp input.

Answer (score 3):

If Graylog exposes a syslog listener you could send them with Docker syslog logging driver.  But since you say you are new to Graylog, have a look at https://github.com/sematext/sematext-agent-docker which should work for you with minimal effort and will be able to also capture Docker metrics and events, not just logs, which is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use log collectors for send logs and traffic to graylog stack
Elastic, beats
Fluentd,
Syslog
TCP/udp  GELF and ets